# Hibernate search with Criteria restriction returning incorrect count

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

The result list is perfect but the **getResultSize()** is incorrect.

I've knocked up some code to illustrate.

```
Criteria criteria2 = this.getSession().createCriteria(Film.class);                      

Criterion genre = Restrictions.eq("genreAlias.genreName", details.getSearch().getGenreName());
criteria2.createAlias("genres", "genreAlias", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN);
criteria2.add(genre);    

criteria2.setMaxResults(details.getMaxRows())
.setFirstResult(details.getStartResult());

FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.createFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser parser2 = new QueryParser("title", new StopAnalyzer() );

org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery2 = parser2.parse( "title:"+details.getSearch()");

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery2, Film.class);
fullTextQuery.setCriteriaQuery(criteria2);

fullTextQuery.getResultList()); // Returns the correctly filtered list
fullTextQuery.getResultSize()); // Returns the retsult size without the genre resrtiction
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/api/org/hibernate/search/jpa/FullTextQuery.html

> int getResultSize()
>
> Returns the number of hits for this search Caution: The number of results might be slightly different from getResultList().size() because getResultList() may be not in sync with the database at the time of query.

You should try to use some of the more specialized queries like this one:

```
    Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("title", q));
    FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Film.class);
    int filmCount = fullTextQuery.getResultSize();
```

and this is how you do pagination requests (I'm guessing you have improperly implemented your paggination):

```
FullTextQuery hits = Search.getFullTextSession(getSession()).createFullTextQuery(query,      Film.class)
.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * perPageItems).setMaxResults(perPageItems);
```

The above works for me every time. You should keep in mind that the result of getResultSize() more of estimate. I use pagination a lot and I have experienced the number changing between pages. So you should say "about xxxx" results.

Comment: lovely. I've adopted the  getResultList().size() as you sugest and it seems fine.

Comment: Whoa! Sorry bit hasty there in my excitement. The getResultList().size() just returns the size of the returned array - which is capped at 10 what I need is the total number of matching records in order to manage the pagination.